# Como trocar o cookie em cada clique?

Tags: php, ajax

Estou fazendo um exercício para trocar o cookie em cada clique através do ajax. Gostaria de setar a cada clique um cookie diferente conforme o conteúdo que foi enviado pelo ajax. Estou enviando esse Ajax para trocar o cookie.

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    $(".cidade").on("click", function(event){
        ///////////////////////
        event.preventDefault();
        cidade = $(this).attr("id");

        $.ajax({
            url: "cookie.php",
            data: {
                cidade: cidade
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês para construir um script simples em PHP para trocar o cookie e que ele seja apresentado no próximo refresh. Fiz isso que acho que tá bem feio e não funcionou. Ele pega o primeiro cookie mas não os outros.

```
<?php
    if( isset($_REQUEST['cidade']) ){
        ///////////
        ob_start();
        setcookie("cidade", "", time()-3600);
        $cidade = $_REQUEST['cidade'];
        setcookie("cidade", $cidade);
        echo $cidade;
        /////////////
    }
?>
```

Comment: E não funcionou?

Comment: Não funcionou. Ele pega o primeiro cookie mas não os outros.

Comment: Como assim o primeiro e não os outros ?

Comment: Boa tarde, aonde exatamente você pega o cookie? Porque nó código só tem a parte que você setou, você disse que ele não pegou os outros cookies, mas no teu código só tem um cookie o `cidade`.